# programmatically create new namespace and put vars in there from another namespace

Tags: clojure

Say I am in `test.core` and I want to create `test.new-ns` and stick a var called `new-method` in there. Is there a way to do that without leaving `test.core`?

This is what I want to do:

```
(ns test.core)

(create-ns 'test.new-ns)
(put-in-ns 'test.new-ns 'new-method {:meta 1} {:value 1})

 *ns* ;=> test.core
 test.new-ns/new-method ;;=> {:value 1}
 (meta #'test.new-ns/new-method) ;; => {:meta 1}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create-ns` actually exists in `clojure.core` and has exactly this signature.

As for `put-in-ns`, that's called `intern`; also, rather than accepting a metadata map as a separate argument, it transfers any metadata attached to the "name" symbol to the Var:

```
(intern 'test.new-ns (with-meta 'new-method {:meta 1}) {:value 1})
```

Reader meta works too, as long as you put it "inside the quote":

```
(intern 'test.new-ns ' ^{:meta 1} new-method {:value 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for `intern`.

> Finds or creates a var named by the symbol name in the namespace
>   ns (which can be a symbol or a namespace), setting its root binding
>   to val if supplied. The namespace must exist. The var will adopt any
>   metadata from the name symbol. Returns the var.

So for your example, it would go a little something like this:

```
(ns test.core)

(create-ns 'test.new-ns)

(intern 'test.new-ns 'new-method {:value 1})
```